# Best practice to convert a packet id to an instance of that class

Tags: java

I'm creating a protocol system for a multiplayer game using as model [the Minecraft's one](https://wiki.vg/Protocol).
Each packet's type is identified by the first byte in the packet, and each packet implements some sort of "Packet" instance. For example, a PacketChat with id 1 and a PacketMove with id 2.
The server will receive a packet, read its id, instantiate a packet of the type corresponding to that id and then parse the remaining data filling its fields.
I thought of several ways to convert the id to a packet, but they all seemed bad to me.

**What I've tried**

- A `Map<Integer, Class<? extends Packet>>` where each class gets registered with a different id and then instantiated on runtime with `map.get(id).newInstance()` (ignoring null checks). This works, but then I have to cast the packet to the corresponding packet type using a lot of instanceof

```
    Packet packet = getPacketById(id);
    if (packet instanceof PacketChat) {
        PacketChat chat = (PacketChat) packet;
    } else if (packet instanceof PacketMove) {
        PacketMove move = (PacketMove) packet;
    }
```

But it seems hard to mantain and with a bad performance

- An enum where each packet is an element. Could be useful, but then I need a system to instantiate some sort of packet parser for each packet, and how should I use them?
- A big switch to call a method for each packet, where there isn't an actual "Packet" class but rather some sort of workers to directly use the parsed values. It does not seem to be practical if I need to add dozens of different packets

**What I need**

Which one should be the best approach? Or maybe a different one I have not thought of?
Thanks

Comment: **and with a bad performance** that is just an assumption. Hint: don't base your design on such unverified assumptions. You see, instanceof checks are pretty cheap, and casting costs even less. Meaning: as long as you manage to do such kind of "type switching" in exactly **one** place (one central method) ... then it isn't necessarily a bad thing. Problems will arise though if you start duplicating such code.

Comment: On way is to use protobuf (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial). There are also other ways that you can search for.

Comment: @GhostCat So the first approach should be correct... if there are, let's say, 50 types of packets will the worst case have to check all the conditions?

Comment: So, if Packet is a superclass of all PacketFoo, why not give it an (abstract?) method `parseTheRemainingData()`, which is what you said needs to be done in each case?

Comment: @passer-by yes this is what the Packet interface has now, but I was wondering about the best way to retrieve the parsed data from the packet since I don't know which packet has actually been instantiated (and I don't want a packet object to access the player instance, for encapsulation)

Comment: There are no silver bullets. In the end, you want to "dispatch" to different code, based on some property of your objects. And there is just a limited number of answers to that: "type switching", polymorphism (what passer-by talks about), and maybe things like the visitor pattern.

Comment: The real answer might be: go with a simple solution first. Do some experiments. Write code for a few of your different types. Then write "client" code that uses the corresponding interfaces. And see how it *feels* to use them. Unless you have more experienced people around that can sit down together with you to talk about your design, and all your requirements, that is like the best thing you can do: try to write code that USES the interfaces, and assess how the different options "work out" for you.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try to put your suggestions into practice